# what happened to "import export: cdt total importer"?

Tags: add-on

I used to run v2.63 in order to convert .cdt to .stl files.  In the newest version, this add-on doesn't seem to exist.  Is there a way I can add on this add-on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to be deprecated - no longer developed - and, thus incompatible with some random change in the Python API. Since it was obsolete, it was removed; try using another format...

Comment: You can always download older versions of blender here: http://download.blender.org/release/